# Why does typescript have its own package manager?

Tags: typescript

Why not bower since it is currently more of a front-end language? The reason I am asking is that you have GIT, NODEJS/NPM and TSD install before you can get up and running with Angular2 and BOWER if you want to use POLYMER.

Comment: TypeScript does not have its own package manager. None of those things you listed, other than npm, are package managers. You don't need npm, or tsd, or nodejs, or git, to use TypeScript.

Comment: On the bower web site in the heading it is described as a "package manager for the web", on the TSD web site it says it is a package manager to search and install TypeScript definition files. The angularjs channel on youtube has a getting started preview video that uses tsd. I realize now the heading was wrong, it should rather be, why are there so many different package managers.

Answer (score -1):

> Why not bower since it is currently more of a front-end language?

Bower works off of NPM. TSD works off of DefinitelyTyped. Different environments => Different tools.